# Can I install Factions/Anti-Griefing tools on a Technic Pack server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-technic-pack

I want to add Factions, or any other sort of anti-griefing plugin, to the server I am hosting, but the .jar provided is only a vanilla server for the [1.7.1.0 Pack](https://www.technicpack.net/modpack/the-1710-pack.453902).

Is it possible to add Bukkit (Factions, or anti-griefing countermeasures) to the server without messing with the rest of the modpack? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Bukkit is a server mod, so you need a modified server file. I don't know what a Vanilla server for a certain pack is, other than just a Vanilla server, but if it's the same as on https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/server, then it won't work for modpacks.

Comment: @FabianRöling The server created with the modpack runs off of vanilla, but is there no way I can set up factions or anti-griefing tools on the server in any way possible?

Comment: I don't know modpacks too much, but if it's a Vanilla server, you can only use client mods, like minimap, shulker box content display, etc., but no server mods (since the server isn't modded), like those that add new blocks/items/entities, change behaviours, etc.

Comment: @FabianRöling I understand it is vanilla, but is there a way I can convert it into a Bukkit server somehow?

Comment: Only by programming in every single modification that Bukkit ever did, which should only take a few years. Why don't you just download a Bukkit server instead?

Comment: @FabianRöling We want to use the 1.7.1.0 Pack and all of its features but with anti-griefing plugins to prevent players from griefing.

Comment: If you want a Bukkit server, use a Bukkit server. Not Vanilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Forge Essentails 1.7.10](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/forge-essentials-74735)

It has a few querks and some of the modules don't really work but it is a server only mod which you can use to prevent most griefing.